# Sphinx - How can one share a directory containing many reStructuredText files among multiple Sphinx projects

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx

I create documentation in Sphinx, my project has the following structure.

```
---my_project
   ---client1
      ---rest_directories_created_by_sphinx
      ---source
          ---index.rst
   ---client2
      ---rest_directories_and_files_created_by_sphinx
      ---source
          ---index.rst
   ---shared
      ---file1.rst
      ---file2.rst
```

In the future there will be more client folders.
In file client1/source/index.rst I need to put in toctree files from directory shared

When I write

```
includepath = ['./shared']
```

I get an Error that toctree in file client1/index.rst contains reference to non existing document.
I have no idea how can i do it?

conf.py is in client1/source and in client2/source.
shared is on the same level as client1 and client2 I want to include in toctree file1.rst and file2.rst from directory shared

Comment: Where is your `conf.py`? Where is `shared`?

Comment: conf.py is in client1/source and in client2/source
shared is on the same level as client1 and client2
I want to include in toctree file1.rst and file2.rst from directory shared
@StevePiercy

Comment: Please edit your question to include the new information. Do not add new information to a comment.